# ResultSet.next() is too slow for an oracle ref cursor

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset, slowdown

I call an oracle procedure from java and it returns a ref cursor as result. I cast the ref cursor to a ResultSet and the iteration starts over it.

```
String query = "{call ...(...)}";
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query,ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(10000); 
.
.
.
stmt.registerOutParameter(x, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
stmt.execute();
Resultset rs = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(x);

while (rs.next()) {    /** Problem occurs here **/
    ...
}
```

The problem is that SOMETIMES (not always) for some specific records the ResultSet.next() method takes too long (like 100 secs). Necessary to mention that the number of returned records is at most 25 and the same query in the database behaves executed normally (executes in about 6 seconds).

As I investigated more, I found out that there is a column in my returned cursor which if removed this problem doesn't occur. That column is actually the ROWNUM() which is included in the result cursor.

```
--ORACLE Query snippet:
OPEN result_cursor FOR 
SELECT "FirstName","LastName", r 
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM r, *
         ... -- query details
         WHERE ROWNUM <= 25)
```

I don't even touch that field in the ResultSet but it still causes this problem (which seems unfair :( ). I tried to convert it to string in the Oracle procedure (by concatenating it with a ' '), assuming that a type conversion might cause this issue, but it made no difference in the situation.
why is this happening?

Comment: Setting your fetch size so high is wasting memory and might be taking a noticeable time to set up and tear down the structures, I suppose. Are you excluding `r` from the final select list, or removing the `rownum <= 25` filter; presumably you have an `order by` in there, are you removing that too?

Comment: @AlexPoole : I have set fetch size to different values (10, 25, ...) and it didn't make any difference. I just exclude the r from the final select list and the query body remains the same. I feel that the ref cursor to ResultSet conversion causes this issue, but I can't find a reason for that.

Comment: Maybe you have a bad execution plan for query which includes `r`; if you're on 10g I'd wonder about bind variable peeking, particularly if it's intermittent. Can you check the execution plans for both queries (using the same bind values)?

Comment: Run an oracle trace on the session and tkprof on it.

Comment: I am logging before and after calling the SP in an outter oracle SP, and the log times show that the SP has been executed in proper time at DB level. Also, as I said, the case doesn't occur when the SP is called from a db client (like navicat). I fetch the cursor in navicat and iterate on it, everything is fine, nobody's hurt. But the same SP call in java (using JDBC) results in aforementioned issue. So It doesn't seem to be an execution plan DB-Side problem. But I'll follow your suggestions for further clues anyway.

Comment: A completly wild -- and probably stupid -- guess: can't this be related to garbage collection?

Answer (score 1):

The field you are talking about, the ROWNUM(), is a changeable value, since rows may be inserted which might actually change the absolute row number - which then needs to be recalculated when the fetch operation performed, to account for any inserts or deletes from the tables returned by the cursor since the last fetch call. Calling rs.next() causes a fetch operation, each time, because this column is a changeable value, even though you're getting the rest of the results quite quickly.

This happens because using a ref cursor KEEPS THE SELECT OPEN while you are navigating the ResultSet.

Comment: Well it makes sense, but what could be the solution?

Comment: Try selecting the result into a temp table, and opening the cursor on the temp table.

Comment: Or just return a normal ResultSet rather than a cursor.